# Selecting which parts of an email mutt saves

Tags: linux, email, mutt

Using the `ignore` function it is possible to cherry pick which header information is displayed in the pager.

This works perfectly.

Saving mail, using the standard s bound functionality or a tagged ;s batch still includes all of the cruft. It does not matter if I save in the mailbox overview or from inside the pager.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to know how to entirely remove particular headers from an e-mail?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes, like Return-Path,Received, Message-ID, and so on. All I'm interested in is the date, who it's from and the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decode-save function, bound to `<Esc>s`, or the decode-copy function, bound to `<Esc>C`, should do what you want, although they may do more decoding of the message than you want.

Comment: Ah, that does work adequately and I will accept your answer a bit later if things stay as they are. I want to keep it open in case someone knows a way to achieve that with an equivalent of the ignore and unignore functions.